# How to cut any string in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a handler function to display data from the spinner on the text view

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(spDanhSachDangKy.getSelectedItem()==null)
                {
                    //show notification
                }
                else
                {
                    String selectText=String.valueOf(spDanhSachDangKy.getSelectedItem());
                    tvShow.setText(selectText);
                }
            }
        });
```

The result will look like this: Table-Restaurant-FoodName-Cost. For example: TB1-HuongDongCoNoi-Pho-14.
Now I want to get the value of cost, what to do?

Comment: String.split()?  String.lastIndexOf()? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html

Comment: `string.substring(startIndex, endIndex)`

Comment: @Zain Great idea, but if the restaurant name length changes, everything is moved. That is true for all the values that come before it (table, restaurant, foodname)

Comment: @mega12345mega .split with regex .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to tokenize your string

```
.
.
.
else {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(selectText, "-"); // if '-' is your delimiter
    String cost = st[st.length - 1]; // assuming you want last token, or you can replace it with position
    tvShow.setText(cost);
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: The statement "String cost = st[st.length - 1];" is incorrect

Comment: didn't check the syntax. StringTokenizer breaks your string into various tokens based on your delimiter.


You can try this also:

String[] result = "this is a test".split("-"); and use result as array of tokens

Answer (score 1):

So,

- **Input:** TB1-HuongDongCoNoi-Pho-14
- **Need to extract:** 14

So you can use regex with [`.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method

- Solution 1: split on the hyphen "-"
- Solution 2: split on the decimal number "//d+"

```
    String text = "TB1-HuongDongCoNoi-Pho-14";

    // Method 1: split on hyphen
    String[] split = text.split("-");
    String value = split[split.length - 1];


    // Method 2: split on number
    String[] split = text.split("//d+");
    String value = split[split.length - 1];
```

Comment: @Thien Nguyen, just like this solution